# ByteArrayBuffer can't be resolved for Android 6.0

Tags: android, eclipse

I was using the **org.apache.http.util.ByteArrayBuffer** package for my android app but now when I am building it for android 6.0, I get the error that ByteArrayBuffer can't be resolved. So, I found that the org.apache.http.util has been removed. What could be the way around this, please help me out.

Here is my code:

```
public static byte[] hexToBytes(String hex) {
            ByteArrayBuffer bytes = new ByteArrayBuffer(hex.length() / 2);
            for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i++) {
                if (hex.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                    continue;
                }

                String hexByte;
                if (i + 1 < hex.length()) {
                    hexByte = hex.substring(i, i + 2).trim();
                    i++;
                } else {
                    hexByte = hex.substring(i, i + 1);
                }

                bytes.append(Integer.parseInt(hexByte, 16));
            }
            return bytes.buffer();
        }
```

Comment: Can't you use a `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream` instead?

Answer (score 2):

You can import the package from a jar file. Download the jar file from:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0-alpha6

Then import into libs folder and add

compile files('libs/AppTracker.jar')

to the build.gradle(Module:app)

So it works for me.